# How to align cucumber examples on a MacBook

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am using Cucumber on IntelliJ (Java), and got a scenario where I have a very long list of examples to be validated from a spreadsheet. I have created examples columns and have plugged them onto my test, now the issue is if I do copy and paste the values from spreadsheet the Cucumber obviously doesn't separate them with a pipe ( | ); which means I have to go and manually enter for each one of them which could both be annoying and time consuming. Is there a quicker way to hack this and get Cucumber to pipe separate the example values?

Examples:

```
| Country | internationalCode |
| Australia | 061 |
| USA | 001 |
....
```

So forth for say 150 rows.

Comment: Store it as CSV and when loading to a spreadsheet, like excel, put delimiter as "|"

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

this one is working: (mac intellij )Alt+Shift+f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).